# Selenium new url hangs webdriver

Tags: python, loops, selenium, url, webdriver

I'm using chromedriver + selenium to try to loop through a website with the same url structure for all their pages like so:

```
for i in range(1,3):
#iterate pages and get url
ureq = "https://somewebsite.com/#page=" + str(i)
driver.get(ureq.strip())

#create
soup = []

#main code here
try:
    #Wait for page to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"some element in the DOM")))

    src = driver.page_source

    #Parse page with bs
    soup = bs(src, "lxml")

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out")
    driver.quit()

#main code

driver.quit()
```

The problem is when the loop fires a second time and the url changes to "#page=2", I can see the webpage and url has changed in the webdriver but the script just hangs. There is no timeout or error message, the script just freezes.

I've also tried placing a print statement before "webDriverWait" to see where the program hangs but that also doesn't fire. I think for some reason, the second get url request is the culprit.

Why is that, or is something else here the issue?

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct URLs?  Anything following `#` is just an instruction to the browser to scroll down to a specific location within the page.  So you're effectively calling `.get()` on the same url twice, which if I recall correctly, browsers are free to ignore.

Comment: What ^ said... my guess is that it's supposed to be a `?` instead. You should be able to go to the website and navigate to page 2 manually and then examine the URL.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a web developer so I didn't know # was for scrolling. My initial route was to just increment the pages since the url structure was predictable. I ended up using XPATH to click the page numbers since they don't have a next button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can obtain the url directly from the `href` attribute of `link` element, the url should work when you enter into address bar directly. But it's not always work, see the below explain for `click` event

But if you obtain the url from address bar after click on some element, you will fail to open the destination page by enter the url into address bar.

Because when you click on the element, there maybe a `click` event triggered which executed a javascript code in background to fetch data from backend or whatever.

For those background stuff, you can't trigger them by enter the url in address bar. So the safety way is to click on the element.

I know Angularjs App acted as such way in most time.

Comment: Thanks, the element was definitely being brought in by jQuery and I didn't know the page wasn't actually refreshing when I entered the new url.